# How can I invoke CreateFile for something like /dev/null in Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I need to call a function in a Windows library that takes as a parameter a handle to a file created by [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). 
In my application, I am not interested in the output that the library generates on this file. Is there a way for me to create a handle to a null file like /dev/null in a *nix OS?

Comment: @user787913 In case you're also looking for `/dev/random` and `/dev/zero` for Windows, see http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ZeroDrv

Comment: @devnull I will keep those in my bookmarks as well, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the built-in `"NUL"` file.